# lsp-mode DataTips

Tags: lsp-mode

In Visual Studio, DataTips is displayed on hovering over a variable, like info about type. Is this something which is included in LSP and can be viewed in lsp-mode?

I don't use a mouse, so it would have to be something like an lsp-data-tips;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found the answer;)

lsp-describe-thing-at-point